# how to call functions based on numbers

Tags: lua, coronasdk

First I stored 10 images in array(i.e. table) from 1-10 as key values and I create a random number using `math.random` function between 0-9., and i need to access the image that is stored in array by the value created by random function, and  need to assign the touch and move(drag and drop)  function for the particular image file alone., other images also needs touch(i.e drag alone)

**Ex:** if the random fn creates no as "5" i need to drag and drop the image `5.png` that is stored in array index as 5 .,other images except `5.png` should not able to drop., (i.e., they are allowed to move in screen but not to drop able in screen)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about the full functionality of a game. I'll explain you the basics. Just understand it and do the rest:

**Creating the elements**

```
  -- Here I'm creating them as array elements for easy access --
  local image = {}
  for i=1,10 do
    image[i] = display.newImageRect("myImage.png",20,20)
    image[i].x = 55*i
    image[i].y = 100
    image[i].tag = i
  end
```

**So, you can assign properties to each images as:**

```
local function imageClicked(event)
   --[[ You can check the image tag here as event.target.tag
        and do the rest based on that. --]]
   print("Touch "..event.phase.." in image["..event.target.tag.."]")
end
for i=1,10 do
    image[i]:addEventListener("touch", imageClicked)
end
```

Keep Coding............. :)